# Flutter skip children in ListView or PageView

Tags: dart, flutter

Let's say I have 4 children in my `PageView` as

```
PageView(
  children: <Widget>[
    Page1(),
    Page2(),
    Page3(), // how to skip this when a condition is false
    Page4(),
  ],
)
```

I want to show `Page3` when a `bool` value is `true`, how do I do that, I thought of putting a `null` but I am not allowed to do that.

Comment: use `PageView.builder` constructor

Comment: What I am supposed to return in `itemBuilder` there for index 2?

Comment: `Page3` or `Page4` depending on your `bool` value

Comment: @pskink Thanks, I got it how to do it using `builder` constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is a better way to make the things happen.

```
List<Widget> list = [];
if (condition) {
  list = [
    Page1(),
    Page2(),
    Page3(), 
    Page4(),
  ];
} else {
  list = [
    Page1(),
    Page2(),
    Page4(),
  ];
}

return PageView(children: list);
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do is with - With `sync*` functions.

`Page2` will be displayed if the `condition` is true.

```
bool condition = true;

PageView(
          children: List.unmodifiable(() sync* {
            yield Center(child: Text('Page1'));   //Page 1
            if (condition) {
              yield Center(child: Text('Page2'));  // Page2(conditional)
            }
            // yield* children;
            yield Center(child: Text('Page3'));  //Page3
          }()),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Beginning with Dart 2.2.2, you can use normal `if` condition.

```
PageView(
  children: <Widget>[
    Page1(),
    Page2(),
    if (_condition) Page3(), // visible only when condition is true
    Page4(),
  ],
)
```